# saving output for next iteration

Tags: mathematical-optimization, cplex, opl

I'm trying to solve MIP problem with IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization studio. All the parameters have been defined. I want to save the output from the first iteration and use this output as input for the next iteration and change some data too. For this purpose; I have written the following main block, but **the result of the first iteration has not been saved for the next iteration**. Which part should I modify?

**the main block:**

```
{string}s={"aa","bb","cc","dd","ee"};

main{
   var source = new IloOplModelSource("subset.mod");
   var cplex = new IloCplex();
   var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);
   var output=0;
     for(var iter=1;iter<=5;iter++)
     {
      var m=Opl.item(thisOplModel.s,iter-1);    
      thisOplModel.M.add(m);
      var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);
      var data= new IloOplDataElements();
    data.M=thisOplModel.M;
    data.N=thisOplModel.N;
    opl.addDataSource(data);
    opl.generate();
         if (iter!=1){
    for (var k in data.M){
    for (var r in data.N){
       opl.x[k][r].LB=output;
       opl.x[k][r].UB=output;}}}
  
    if (cplex.solve()) {
        writeln("OBJ = " + cplex.getObjValue());
      } else {
         writeln("No solution");
      }
      opl.postProcess();
      
   for (var r in data.N){
     for (var k in data.M){ 
       if (output==1){       
         output=opl.x[k][r].solutionValue;
       }
   }
  data.end();    
  opl.end();
       
    }
}
```

**The result:**

```
======================================
ITERATION 1
M= {"aa"}
OBJ = 4.1
x[aa][b] = 1
x[aa][c] = 1

======================================
ITERATION 2
M= {"aa" "bb"}
OBJ = 0

======================================
ITERATION 3
M= {"aa" "bb" "cc"}
OBJ = 0

======================================
ITERATION 4
M= {"aa" "bb" "cc" "dd"}
OBJ = 0

======================================
ITERATION 5
M= {"aa" "bb" "cc" "dd" "ee"}
OBJ = 0
```

could you help me? I asked this question before, but I did not get a result..
Regards

Answer (score 0):

your issue is no CPLEX or OPL but pure scripting

You wrote

```
if (output==1){       
         output=opl.x[k][r].solutionValue;
       }
```

but you never set output to 1 so this line is never called

Comment: Thank you for your reply; I deleted "if (output==1)", but the results did not change.

Comment: Setting breakpoints and debugging https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/22.1.0?topic=eclipse-setting-breakpoints-debugging